# How to make architecture decisions that could apply for any application

Tags: architecture, selection

I am serious getting bogged down by various technologies that's available today. For example, to get to a point where I can select a Java Framework; I have numerous options in market - Apache Wicket, Tapestry, Click, Struts, Seam, Spring, grails, play framework. Then comes the database, ORM, Caching, JavaScript framework and so on. 
Any small mistake here would have a serious effect during development or during maintenance phase, which I feel could be brought down with expert decision making.

I would like to learn from experts here, how they decide during such an architecture decision making phase. As a generic pattern what are the important decision points to consider when selecting a framework and related technology stack for any web application development that's done from scratch.

For example, if I am making architectural decisions for a social networking site how should I go about listing down the various technologies, categorize it, evaluate and shortlist the final tech stack?

I am looking out for a generic pattern or process for decision making which could help all. The process should be applicable for any application. (Banking solution, Social network or anything else). Please point any books/resources that could help.

I looked at the below two sites which SO showed as relevant, but it did not answer my question precisely.

[How to make decisions while choosing a project in an IT company?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505906/how-to-make-decisions-while-choosing-a-project-in-an-it-company)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713427/social-network-development-project-technology-decision-making

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a list of all of your available technology, and create a table that evaluates each of your criteria with a value.  For example, your columns might be "Execution Speed", "Development speed", "price", "scalability", etc, while the columns are each available vendor/technology choice.   Create a table like this for each software choice you need to make within your stack (DB, ORM, Caching, etc.)

Then take a look at your project, and pick which criteria you most value  For example, some projects need to be cheap and don't have much need to scale, while others can be high-cost but need very strong scalability.  Then, from each table, pick an option that best matches these requirements.  Voilá!  There's your stack.

Comment: +1 You're on the right path. The key trick is determining what the initial criteria is, and their relative weight/importance.

Comment: @oneworld, this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639732/make-desicions-for-app-development/7643514#7643514

Comment: @AdrianK Yeah, maybe making explicit tables about the technologies' abilities is a little much, but you could think of it as a figurative step - know the strengths and weaknesses of each technology, and then actually write down the initial criteria and think hard about what applies.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers AdrianK and Tim. The links and information pointed here is pretty useful for my case. Thanks a lot :)